# How to get the image & text coordinates of pdf with respect to page using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to remove the text that appears on an image in a PDF file. To accomplish this, I'm using the pdfbox library to obtain the image and character coordinates.

Initially, I attempted to retrieve the image coordinates using the code snippet provided below. Since the image coordinate system and text coordinate system differ in PDF files, I converted the image coordinates to the text coordinate system. However, I'm uncertain about the accuracy of the conversion formula. I stored all the image coordinates in an array called "coordinates".

```
@Override
protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
    String operation = operator.getName();
    if ("Do".equals(operation)) {
        COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get(0);
        PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
        if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) xobject;
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
            
            // Print image information
            System.out.println("\nImage [" + objectName.getName() + "]");
            
            Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
            float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
            float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();
            
            // Print position of image in the PDF in terms of user space units
            System.out.println("position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
            // Print raw size of the image in pixels
            System.out.println("raw image size  = " + imageWidth + ", " + imageHeight + " in pixels");
            // Print displayed size of the image in user space units
            System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in user space units");
            
            PDRectangle pdRectangle = getCurrentPage().getMediaBox();
            int pageHeight = (int) pdRectangle.getHeight();
            int pageWidth = (int) pdRectangle.getWidth();
            
            // Convert the image coordinates to text coordinates
            int x1 = (int) (ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ctmNew.getShearX() - ctmNew.getScalingFactorX());
            int x2 = (int) (ctmNew.getTranslateX() + imageWidth);
            int y2 = (int) (pageHeight - ctmNew.getTranslateY());
            int y1 = (int) (pageHeight - (ctmNew.getTranslateY() + ctmNew.getShearY() + imageHeight));
            
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(x1, y1, x2, y2, pageNum);
            coordinates.add(coordinate);
        } else if (xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
            PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject) xobject;
            showForm(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Later, I obtained the character coordinates using the following code and checked if the character lies within the image coordinates.

```
@Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) 
    {
        PDPage pdpage = getCurrentPage() ;
        int pageno = getCurrentPageNo() ;
        super.processTextPosition(text) ;

        PDColor pdcolor = getGraphicsState().getStrokingColor() ;
        Color jcolor = null ;
        try {  jcolor = new Color(pdcolor.toRGB()) ;  } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace() ; }
        jcolor = jcolor == null ? Color.BLACK : jcolor ;
        PColor fontcolor = new PColor(jcolor.getRed(), jcolor.getGreen(), jcolor.getBlue(), jcolor.getAlpha()) ;
        
        String unicode = text.getUnicode() ;
        
        float angle = text.getDir() ;
        float x1 = text.getX() ;
        float y1 = text.getY() ;
        float height = text.getHeight() ;
        // float height = ( text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getCapHeight()) / 1000 * text.getFontSize() ;
        float width = text.getUnicode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? text.getWidthOfSpace() : text.getWidth() ;
        PDFont font = text.getFont() ;
        float fontsize = text.getFontSize() ;
        float ptfontsize = text.getFontSizeInPt() ;
        
        float x2 = x1 + width ;
        float y2 = y1 + height ;
        // System.out.println("Height=" + height) ;
        
        String fontname = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontName().toUpperCase() ;
        boolean bold = fontname.toUpperCase().contains("BOLD") ;
        boolean italics = fontname.toUpperCase().contains("ITALIC") ;
        fontname = fontname.replaceAll("BOLD", "").replaceAll("ITALICS", "").replaceAll("ITALIC", "").replaceAll("REGULAR", "").replaceAll("\\-", "").trim().toUpperCase() ; 
        
        
        PPage page = pages().containsKey(pageno) ? pages().get(pageno) : null ;
        if ( page == null )
            page = new PPage(0.0f, 0.0f, pdpage.getCropBox().getWidth(), pdpage.getCropBox().getHeight(), pageno, 0.0f, new PColor(255, 255, 255, 0), new ArrayList<PCharacter>()) ;
        
        PCharacter pchar = new PCharacter(pageno, angle, x1, y1, x2, y2, new PColor(255, 255, 255, 0), unicode, fontname, fontsize, ptfontsize, fontcolor, bold, italics, false, false) ;


        boolean isPresentWithinCoordinate = PSVGReader.coordinates.stream().anyMatch(coordinate -> x1 >= coordinate.getX1()
                && x2<=coordinate.getX2() && y1 >=coordinate.getY1()
                && y2 <= coordinate.getY2() && pageno == coordinate.getPageNo());

        if(!isPresentWithinCoordinate) {
            page.rawCharacters().add(pchar);
            System.out.println("\n pageno="+ pageno + "  pchar="+ pchar + " X1="+ x1 + " X2=" + x2 + " Y1="+ y1 + " Y2=" + y2);     
        }else {
            page.rawCharacters().add(pchar) ;
        }

        pages().put(pageno, page) ;


    }
```

However, I noticed that the character coordinates and image coordinates do not match. I suspect that my method of converting the image coordinates to the text coordinate system is incorrect. Could you please assist me in accurately converting the image coordinate system to the character coordinate system?